# An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement performing instruction in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to perform an `UPDATE` summarizing the values ​​of a table that are in the `VAL_APURADO` column grouped by the payment plan code in the `COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO` column. When performing the statement, SQL Server returns the following error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
UPDATE TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
SET VAL_TOTAL_APURADO = SUM(VAL_TOTAL_APURADO)
WHERE (
    SELECT SUM(VAL_TOTAL_APURADO) 
    FROM TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
    WHERE TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO.COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO = TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO.COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
    GROUP BY COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
  ) > 5000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query makes no sense, as you are taking the `SUM` from the base table, not from the `WHERE` subquery. you would need to convert this to a join or `APPLY`.

You can in any case do this more efficiently and concisely with a window function in an updatable CTE

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      sum_APURADO = SUM(md.VAL_TOTAL_APURADO) OVER (PARTITION BY md.COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO, md.COD_MOVIMENTO)
    FROM TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO md
)
UPDATE cte
SET VAL_TOTAL_APURADO = cte.sum_APURADO
WHERE cte.sum_APURADO > 5000;
```

Comment: I need to summarize the VAL_TOTAL_APURADO grouping by COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO and COD_MOVIMENTO, I adjusted your query but it's still not working

Comment: Just add it to the `partition by` clause, I have done that now

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
SET    VAL_TOTAL_APURADO = AggregateQ.Sum_TOTAL_APURADO 
FROM TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO,SUM(VAL_TOTAL_APURADO) AS Sum_TOTAL_APURADO  
    FROM   TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
    GROUP BY COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
) AS AggregateQ ON AggregateQ.COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO = TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO.COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO AND AggregateQ.Sum_TOTAL_APURADO > 5000
```

Comment: I need to summarize the VAL_TOTAL_APURADO grouping by COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO and COD_MOVIMENTO, I adjusted your query but it's still not working